# Where can I find historical political affiliation data for the United States?

Tags: data, data-mining

I am collaborating on a research paper where one of our variables is political affiliation across the United States. I will be creating a series of historical maps. I'm looking for the percentage of the population that is Republican, Democrat, and Independent in each zip code in the US. If zip code isn't available, county would work too, or statewide if nothing else. I've searched online and have only found 2008 and 2012 election data.

Does anyone know where I could find this historical political affiliation data? I need data from 1980 to present day.

Comment: http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/index.php might be a good starting point?

Comment: @AndrewTice Thanks for the link. It has some good information, but it doesn't provide raw data to work with. I need it in some usable file format.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a website http://uselectionatlas.org/RESULTS/, where you can choose different parameters/facts. For example you can select the year (starting in 1789) and a map will show you the results. But you have the option to get the data too. I hope it helps!

Comment: Had checked that one .... $60-80 per year for each download

Comment: Alright, but if I select e.g. a year (1980) and click on maps e.g. "Democrate" I get a table with the results for each district and the percentage. I know, it's not the easiest way to get the data, but it's an option, isn't it?